# inject RavenTestDriver in my xunit to my main code in .netcore

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, xunit, ravendb, raventestdriver

I have this repository in my project that interacts with raven DB:

```
  public class RavenRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>, IDisposable
    where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        protected readonly IAsyncDocumentSession _session;
        public RavenRepository(IAsyncDocumentSession session)
        {
            _session = session;
        }
    //other methods like add search edit update 
}
```

Ass you can see my constructor expects an `IAsyncDocumentSession` .I want to use `RavenTestDriver` in my test.So I have to pass `RavenTestDriver Session` to this class .Here is my test code :

```
  public class TestHostBuilder: RavenTestDriver, IAsyncLifetime
    {
        protected override void PreInitialize(IDocumentStore documentStore)
        {
            documentStore.Conventions.MaxNumberOfRequestsPerSession = 50;
            ConfigureServer(new TestServerOptions
            {
                //DataDirectory = "C:\\RavenDBTestDir",
                CommandLineArgs = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string> { "--RunInMemory=true", },
                FrameworkVersion = null,
            });
        }
        public HttpClient _httpClient = null!;

        public async Task InitializeAsync()
        {
           var store = GetDocumentStore();
           var  session= store.OpenAsyncSession();
            var hostBuilder = easy.api.Program.CreateHostBuilder(new string[0])
             .ConfigureWebHost(webHostBuilder =>
             {
                 webHostBuilder.UseTestServer();


             })
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, InitRequest>();
                services.AddScoped<IAsyncDocumentSession, ?????)>();
            });

            var host = hostBuilder.Start();

            _httpClient = host.GetTestClient();

        }

        public Task DisposeAsync()
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }


    }
```

As you can see I create a store and session using ravenTestDriver but I don't know how can I inject this session to `IAsyncDocumentSession`

**Updated**

I added this code but again my code uses the main database not `raventestdriver` why ?

```
services.AddSingleton<IAsyncDocumentSession>((c) =>
{
    return GetDocumentStore().OpenAsyncSession(new SessionOptions()
    {
        Database="test-server"
    });
});
```

Comment: I found this but it doesn't work why :
                services.AddSingleton<IAsyncDocumentSession>((c) =>
                {
                    return GetDocumentStore().OpenAsyncSession(new SessionOptions()
                    {
                        Database="test-server"
                    });
                });

Comment: Could you please share code how RavenRepository<TEntity> and  IAsyncDocumentSession service representing main database are registered.